# Unset people property using mixpanel JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I try to remove a property for a user using mixpanel JavaScript API. As I can see, there is only a method set, but no method unset. I tried to set the property with undefined or null but when I do so, the property still exists with no value. I would like to totally remove it as we can do it with the mixpanel interface. Is that possible?

Thanks for your help!

Some code:

```js
// Let set the property 'foo' with a value 'bar' to the current user
mixpanel.people.set("foo", "bar");

// Now, let unset this proprety
// Oops, there is no method unset...
// Let's try something else
mixpanel.people.set("foo"); // nop...
mixpanel.people.set("foo", undefined); // nop...
mixpanel.people.set("foo", null); // the value is now empty but the property still exists
```

Comment: It would help to include some code with your question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: From the docs it looks like the only way to unset a property is to delete the  user using `mixpanel.people.delete_user()`. https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.people.delete_user

Comment: What's you saying is that you cannot unset a property, you have to delete the user and set all the other properties back? That's sound pretty ugly :/

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible with the JavaScript API, but you could write a backend a script that removes properties with an empty value.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 2):

The Android MixPanel library (v4.6.4) has an `unset(String)` method for people properties, perhaps the JavaScript API has an equivalent, which I would assume to be:

```
mixpanel.people.unset("foo");
```

Perhaps this did not exist back in August.

Comment: are you sure about that? I just tried: 
mixpanel.people.unset
undefined

Comment: The only thing I'm sure about is that the Android MixPanel library (v4.6.4) has an `unset` method for people properties.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't see that you were talking about the android SDK. No there is no equivalent in the Javascript SDK unfortunatelly :(

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't great. It seems odd that they have included this in Android, but not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

`mixpanel.people.unset("123", "my_unused_property")`

or

`mixpanel.people.unset("123", ["my_unused_property1", "my_unused_property2",..] )`

This is unset's signature `(distinct_id, property_name)`

`distinct_id` is the user id in mixpanel

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mixpanel/mixpanel-ruby/Mixpanel/People#unset-instance_method